# What is this polarized 2-pin connector?

Tags: identification, connector

I'm trying to replicate a system using these two-pin connectors and have been having trouble finding them. They look like Molex type connectors to me, but I can't find similar versions. The pins are about 4mm apart.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a proprietary derivative of an IEC appliance connector.  What's the voltage?  is it AC or DC?  Can you give us any more information about the system?

Comment: looks like there is something printed on the connector in the first picture

Comment: From the documentation I have available, it's DC from 5-30 V and 20 mA

Comment: The print is the numbers 1-8 in a circle with an arrow pointing to the 8

Comment: Screams "proprietary" to me....

Comment: What is the context? Where are these used? What is the country of origin?

Comment: Country of origin is the US and these are used for sending gate signals (digital on) to activate external systems from a larger board. They're used to manage experimental apparatus in a research setting.